# Unable to switch frames to get text

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get text from a div tag that's below an iframe tag. This is the code I'm using:

```
  try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='vjs-container-iframe']/a")))
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
  try:
    driver.switch_to.iframe('vjs-container-iframe')
    description0=driver.find_element_by_id('jobDescriptionText').getText()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    counts=counts+1
    break
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I'm getting this error for the first half of the code:

`Message:`

The rest is just blank

And this error for the second half:

`SwitchTo' object has no attribute 'iframe`

Comment: `driver.switch_to.frame` not `iframe`

Answer (score 1):

It is not `iframe` instead it is `frame`.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ""))
```

you can try with any unique locator, in place of xpath, that is it could be `id`, `class name`, css selector etc.

or

```
driver.switch_to.frame('vjs-container-iframe')
```

Also, `.getText()` is for `Java`, in Python we have `.text`

```
description0 = driver.find_element_by_id('jobDescriptionText').text
```

also, I see you are using `break`, not sure if you are in loop, if not then it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems

1. it should be

```py
description0 = driver.find_element_by_id('jobDescriptionText').text
```

instead of

```
description0=driver.find_element_by_id('jobDescriptionText').getText()
```

2. It should be

```
driver.switch_to.frame('vjs-container-iframe')
```